# isEqual with structure pointers in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am getting an error while trying to compare with the pointer to the structure.

```
-(BOOL)findAndRemoveEvent:(const stRs232Timer*)pEvent
{
    int index;
    index = [m_cPendingEventList count];
    for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
    {
        if(([m_cPendingEventList objectAtIndex:i]) isEqual:pEvent)
        {
            NSLog(@"Found the event to remove!!");
            [m_cPendingEventList removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"Event Removed!!");
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

pEvent is the pointer to the structure stRs232Timer.

Error:Expecte ')' before isEqual.I'm sure that I havent made any mistake with the 
paranthesis.

Comment: You're missing the square brackets around the call to `isEqual:` -- `if([[m_cPendingEventList objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:pEvent])` Besides that, if that isn't an ObjC object, you probably shouldn't be comparing it using `isEqual:`

Comment: How exactly are you storing the `structs` inside the array?

Comment: @Josh Caswell:The error got cleared and i'm getting a warning like this."passing argument 1 of isEqual from incompatible pointer type".seems like what Bavarious told is correct.We cant comapare NSObjects with the structure objects.

Comment: @Bavarious:I'm storing the struct into the mutable array through NSData.

Comment: Yes, that's because it's not an object, as I mentioned. If you want to compare two struct pointers, use `==`. Note that this compares the addresses, not the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ways

```
-(BOOL)findAndRemoveEvent:(const stRs232Timer*)pEvent
    {
        int index;
        index = [m_cPendingEventList count];
        for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
        {
            stRs232Timer* tempEvent = (stRs232Timer*)[m_cPendingEventList objectAtIndex:i];
            if( tempEvent  == pEvent )
            {
                NSLog(@"Found the event to remove!!");
                [m_cPendingEventList removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                NSLog(@"Event Removed!!");
            }
        }
        return YES;
  }
```

Good luck !

Comment: but he can ! He can store pointer to struct in a NSMutable array !

Comment: @ViTo Brothers Apoyan:I am getting a warning when i tried to do by the first method you have given in your answer."Initialisation from incompatible pointer type."

Comment: I remove first method ! try this one !

Comment: I forget to do the typecasting so is that warning!.Its working.Thanks.

Comment: try to change the line: stRs232Timer* tempEvent = [m_cPendingEventList objectAtIndex:i];
as stRs232Timer* tempEvent = (stRs232Timer*)[m_cPendingEventList objectAtIndex:i]; and try again

Comment: You can't just typecast an `NSData` object and make it act like an arbitrary struct.

Comment: @ViTo Brothers:I'm checking it.I need to pass the structure pointer according to the key value that is stored in map.some looping needs to be done.Will tell you if get output.